# CPU Usage of an instance with Cloudwatch API

Tags: c#, amazon-ec2, cpu-usage

How do i get the CPU usage of an instance in c#?
I've read [Amazon EC2 - how to get available ram and cpu usage via AWS API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533904/amazon-ec2-how-to-get-available-ram-and-cpu-usage-via-aws-api/7053098#7053098) already, but i can't get it working.

NameValueCollection appConfig = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;

```
        var client = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonCloudWatchClient(
                appConfig["AWSAccessKey"],
                appConfig["AWSSecretKey"]
                );

        var dimension = new Dimension
            {
                  Name = "InstanceId",
                  Value = "<i-ad20b4db>",
            };

        var request = new GetMetricStatisticsRequest();
        request.MetricName = "CPUUtilization";
        request.Period = 60;
        request.Statistics.Add("Maximum");
        request.Dimensions.Add(dimension);
        request.Namespace = "AWS/EC2";
        request.Unit = "Percent";

        var currentTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var startTime = currentTime.AddSeconds(-5);
        string currentTimeString= currentTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
        string startTimeString= startTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");

        request.StartTime = Convert.ToDateTime( startTimeString);
        request.EndTime = Convert.ToDateTime(currentTimeString);

        var response = client.GetMetricStatistics(request);

        if ( response.GetMetricStatisticsResult.Datapoints.Count > 0)
            {
                 var dataPoint = response.GetMetricStatisticsResult.Datapoints[0];
                 Console.WriteLine( "Instance: {0} CPU Max load: {1}",  dimension.Value, dataPoint.Maximum);

            }
```

Comment: What specifically did you try?  Post some code.  What specific errors do you get?

Comment: NameValueCollection appConfig = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
            
            var client = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonCloudWatchClient(
                    appConfig["AWSAccessKey"],
                    appConfig["AWSSecretKey"]
                    );

var dimension = new Dimension
{
    Name = "InstanceId",
    Value = "<i-ad20b4db>",
};
            
var request = new GetMetricStatisticsRequest();
request.MetricName = "CPUUtilization";

Comment: request.Period = 60;
request.Statistics.Add("Maximum");
request.Dimensions.Add(dimension);
request.Namespace = "AWS/EC2";
request.Unit = "Percent";

var currentTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
var startTime = currentTime.AddSeconds(-5);
string currentTimeString= currentTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
string startTimeString= startTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");

Comment: request.StartTime = Convert.ToDateTime( startTimeString);
request.EndTime = Convert.ToDateTime(currentTimeString);
reques
var response = client.GetMetricStatistics(t);

if ( response.GetMetricStatisticsResult.Datapoints.Count > 0)
{
    var dataPoint = response.GetMetricStatisticsResult.Datapoints[0];
    Console.WriteLine(
        "Instance: {0} CPU Max load: {1}",  dimension.Value,
        dataPoint.Maximum);
    }    but datapoint.count stays empty

Comment: it'd be much better if you edited your question and pasted the source in there; it will get formatted and be much easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple proof of concept for showing the CPU Utilization during the last two days. I think there will be a datapoint like every half an hour, but you can easily change by changing the value of the Period property in the GetMetricStatisticsRequest object.

```
AmazonCloudWatch cw = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonCloudWatchClient(accessKey, secretKey, new AmazonCloudWatchConfig().WithServiceURL("https://eu-west-1.monitoring.amazonaws.com"));

        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            Dimension dim = new Dimension() { Name = "InstanceId", Value = GetInstanceName(amazonInstance) };
            System.Collections.Generic.List<Dimension> dimensions = new List<Dimension>() { dim };

            string startTime = startTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2).ToString()).ToUniversalTime().ToString("s"); // "2010-09-29T11:00:00+01:00";

            GetMetricStatisticsRequest reg = new GetMetricStatisticsRequest()
            {
                MeasureName = "CPUUtilization",
                Period = 1800
                Statistics = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>() { "Average" },
                Dimensions = dimensions,
                Namespace = "AWS/EC2",
                EndTime = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("s"), //has to be in this format: 2010-09-29T14:00:00+01:00;
                StartTime = startTime
            };

            var points = cw.GetMetricStatistics(reg).GetMetricStatisticsResult.Datapoints.OrderBy(p => p.Timestamp);

            data.Columns.Add("Average");
            data.Columns.Add("TimeStamp");
            foreach (var p in points)
            {
                DataRow row = data.NewRow();
                row["Average"] = Math.Round(p.Average, 0);
                row["TimeStamp"] = DateTimeOffset.Parse(p.Timestamp).LocalDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

                data.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
    catch (AmazonCloudWatchException ex)
                {
                    if (ex.ErrorCode.Equals("OptInRequired"))
                        throw new Exception("You are not signed in for Amazon EC2.");
                    else
                        throw;
                }
```

Comment: new AmazonCloudWatchConfig().WithServiceURL("https://eu-west-1.monitoring.amazonaws.com"));
"WithServiceURL" doesn't exist?

Comment: change it to set the .ServiceURL property with the appropriate host.

Comment: @Joe i am using service url ="https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/" and getting error The requested version (2010-08-01) of service AmazonEC2 does not exist"

Answer (score 1):

This is my final code which works for me. 
I have added new user in the IAM aws management console then i have Attached CloudWatchfullacess Policy to new user then i have used this user Accesskey & secret key in this Code.

```
var  cw =AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonCloudWatchClient("AccessKey","secretkey",Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USWest2);

    DataTable data = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        Dimension dim = new Dimension() { Name = "InstanceId", Value = "InstanceId of you EC2 Server" };
        System.Collections.Generic.List<Dimension> dimensions = new List<Dimension>() { dim };

        string  startTime1 = DateTimeOffset.Parse(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-60).ToString()).ToUniversalTime().ToString("s");


        GetMetricStatisticsRequest reg = new GetMetricStatisticsRequest()
        {
            MetricName = "CPUUtilization",
            Period = 60,
            Statistics = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>() { "Average","Minimum","Maximum" },
            Dimensions = dimensions,
            Namespace = "AWS/EC2",
            EndTime = DateTime.Now, //Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("s")), //has to be in this format: 2010-09-29T14:00:00+01:00;
            StartTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(Convert.ToInt32(-15)),// Convert.ToDateTime(startTime1),
        };

        var points = cw.GetMetricStatistics(reg).GetMetricStatisticsResult.Datapoints.OrderBy(p => p.Timestamp);

        data.Columns.Add("Average");
        data.Columns.Add("TimeStamp");
        foreach (var p in points)
        {
            DataRow row = data.NewRow();
            row["Average"] = Math.Round(p.Average, 0);
            row["TimeStamp"] = p.Timestamp; //DateTimeOffset.Parse(Convert.ToDateTime(p.Timestamp)).LocalDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
            data.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = data;


    }
    catch (AmazonCloudWatchException ex)
            {
                if (ex.ErrorCode.Equals("OptInRequired"))
                    throw new Exception("You are not signed in for Amazon EC2.");
                else
                    throw;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pleas also note that when you want to get CPU usage or any other type of metric, you should be wary of the time-stamp you include in the request. This is because it can take more than 48 hours for data to become available in CloudWatch (according to Amazon).

That is why I personally try to retrieve data from about 3-4 days ago as sometimes CloudWatch will not return any data even if the request and the code are all correct as it does not have any data to publish from the previous day or two.

For more information check this URL and scroll down to StartTime: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_GetMetricStatistics.html